# Flutter Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 8

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to run flutter app on Apple Simulator but I can't able to run it, I got errors as below. this project woking in another Apple Mac book pro. What went wrong here?
I tried `flutter clean` then `flutter run` this wasn't works

[image]

```
Prasaths-MacBook-Pro:Foodom_ios prasathsivanathan$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            2.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[12138]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1eec8c188) and ??
    (0x115c482b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[12138]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1eec8c1d8) and ?? (0x115c48308). One
    of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/U
    tilities/FIRAuthURLPresenter.m:24:
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/U
    tilities/FIRAuthDefaultUIDelegate.h:18:24: error: 'TARGET_OS_WATCHOS' is not defined, evaluates to 0
    [-Werror,-Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_]
    #if !TARGET_OS_OSX && !TARGET_OS_WATCHOS
                           ^
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'geolocator' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'google_maps_flutter' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'location_permissions' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'fluttertoast' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseDatabase' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use
    a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target
    'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'firebase_database' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Foodom_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS
    Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Comment: did you resolve it?

Comment: Actually not yet, but the solution is *Add Developer Certificate* then try to Run, let me know after that